# SFML, background objects

Tags: c++, sprite, sfml, pixel

[Hi everybody.
I am currently creating a Lion King game(C++, SFML).

I already have a background for a specific level(original background from the game, it's a sprite that i found).

The problem is this - 
I want to be able to collide with all those big rocks: collusion from underneth means that it's a "celling" of some sort, collusion from above means that I land (and be able to walk) on the rock, etc.

How do you think I should approch that problem? Should I have a map with all coords of the rocks(by pixels) and then check for collusion? Ss there a better way to do it?
Thank you!][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgiRB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qug9.png)

Comment: You should ask your question in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.
But AABB-Collision might be what you are looking for. You propably have to add clipings to your image manually, if you want to avoid advanced image processing

Comment: That's not "background" if you interact with it. You should accept this and start programming these rocks as objects that can be interacted with.